Right-click in VS Code (Code Server) opens 'Paste' instead of the context menu
I've got an issue where when I try to right click anywhere in Visual Studio Code (specifically Code Server) it pops up with a "Paste" context menu. The menu is grayed out for a second or so and then allows me to click paste, which will function.
The issue is that it replaces the standard context menu and only has the paste option.

I can right click twice and get the normal context menu (though this is very annoying). As you can the paste option is grayed out, which I assume is the intended behavior since there is this extra paste context menu.

Interestingly, when I record my screen, if I capture my mouse cursor the recording does NOT capture the Paste box, leading me to believe that this may actually be a KDE Plasma (Wayland) issue. (The right side caption should say Paste not Pause )

emphasized text

In general, I would like to disable this secondary paste context menu if possible. I should note that I've had this exact issue on several machines, weather they are accessed locally or externally, and with and without https enabled.
Current specs:
Operating System: Kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64
Browser: Mozilla Firefox 133.0.3 (64-bit)
Display Manager: KDE Plasma (Wayland)
Url: https://localhost:10000 (configured in the .config/code-server/
config.yaml file)
Config.yaml
bind-addr: 127.0.0.1:10000
auth: none
password:
cert: true

I am hosting the code server on the same machine I am access it on, but I have this same issue when using code server on several of my other servers (but NOT all of them!)
Please let me know if there is any more information I can provide to solve this.

I found the solution from user noverby on Github
"Just set dom.events.testing.asyncClipboard to true." (This is in about:config in Firefox)
